# How do I open a file in its default program - Linux

Tags: c, linux

How do I programmatically open a file in its default program in Linux (im using Ubuntu 10.10).

For example, opening *.mp3 will open the file in Movie Player (or something else).

Comment: Ubuntu by default comes with firefox and if you can run `firefox` command from your terminal .... you can make it right.... Have a look on my solution....and see if this works for you

Answer (score 7):

You need to run *gnome-open, kde-open, or exo-open,* depending on which desktop you are using.

I believe there is a project called *xdg-utils* that attempts to provide a unified interface to the local desktop.

So, something like:

```
snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%s %s", "xdg-open", the_file);
system(s);
```

Beware of code injection. It's safer to bypass scripting layers with user input, so consider something like:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
  execl("/usr/bin/xdg-open", "xdg-open", the_file, (char *)0);
  exit(1);
}
// parent will usually wait for child here
```

Comment: `xdg-open` calls the appropiate one.

Comment: @ninjalj, excellent, I was hoping the pkg did exactly that. I think it's what Chrome uses.

Comment: though I'd recommend using `execv*` instead of `system`.

Comment: @Stepan: the filename, which, if you are using `system`, is a pretty obvious attack vector.

Comment: Anyway, `execl("xdg-open", "xdg-open", file, (char *) NULL)` is much safer. (Of course, after a `fork()`).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 10.10 is based on GNOME.  So, it would be good idea to use 
`g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri()`.

Something like this should work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        gboolean ret;
        GError *error = NULL;

        g_type_init();

        ret = g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri("file:///etc/passwd",
                                                NULL,
                                                &error);
        if (ret)
                g_message("worked");
        else
                g_message("nop: %s", error->message);

        return 0;
}
```

BTW, `xdg-open`, a shell script, tries to determin your desktop environment and call a known helper like `gvfs-open` for GNOME, `kde-open` for KDE, or something else.  `gvfs-open` ends up calling `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri()`.

Comment: I prefer this method if the application already depends on GNOME.

Comment: I recommend you don't use this function, it does not seem to respect your mime settings. On Xfce, I set all browser and browser-related associations to `librewolf` but it still spawns `firefox` for urls. I have this issue rarely with other programs too, probably always those that use this function...

Comment: @phil294, that's your mis-configuration.  Try `gio mime x-scheme-handler/https` to see how your system answers.  If it recommends firefox, try running `strace gio mime x-scheme-handler/https 2>&1 | grep open | grep -v -e ') = -1' -e O_DIRECTORY`, and grep though each files to see which file you have your wrong settings are.

Answer (score 0):

**A simple solution with less coding:**

I've tested this program on my Ubuntu and it is working fine, and if I am not wrong you are looking for something like this

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("firefox file:///dox/song.mp3");
    return 0;
}
```