# triggering vlc player from c++ code

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vlc

I have some songs which I am want to play via code I have vlc player installed in ubuntu, I would like the code to play all the songs in the specified folder via vlc player... Is there a work around for this ? Any help will be appriciated.

```
    int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{   

    char *input=argv[1];
    if(input=="play"){

        //trigger vlc

}
}
```

the folder will already have all the required songs.. what is the way to trigger vlc with those songs

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143100/how-do-i-open-a-file-in-its-default-program-linux). Well, not quite the same, but probably what you meant (what if they don't use vlc?)

Comment: @BoBTFish: Vlc is specific in this case

Comment: [`g_app_info_launch`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-launch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a prototype for you, its unsafe and does no error checking but it works.

Code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int scan(std::string dir, std::vector<std::string> &files)
{
    DIR* dr = opendir(dir.c_str());
    struct dirent *drp;

    while ((drp = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
    {
        struct stat s;
        stat((dir + "/" + std::string(drp->d_name)).c_str(), &s);

        if (s.st_mode & S_IFREG)
        {
            files.push_back(std::string(drp->d_name));
        }
    }

    closedir(dr);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::string dir = ".", cmd = "vlc";
    std::vector<std::string> files, vfiles;

    scan(dir, files);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        if (files[i].substr(files[i].find(".")) == ".mp3")
        {
            vfiles.push_back(std::string(files[i]));
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vfiles.size(); i++)
    {
        cmd += " " + dir + "/" + vfiles[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", cmd.c_str());
    system(cmd.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
vlc ./test.mp3 ./test2.mp3
```

---

What it does is: it lists all files in the specified folder `"."` by default, it checks that the file is actually a file not a folder, it then makes a list of all the files that end with `".mp3"` and then runs `vlc file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file4.mp3`. VLC will play all the listed files in order.

Using (`VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower`) on Windows 8 after adding it to `Path`.

Comment: @Rishabh So what's your point? [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) is cross platform and so is `dirent`.

Comment: How are you specifying the folder where the files are stored

Comment: @Rishabh You can take the path to the folder from `argv`, if its missing it can default to `"."`, meaning the current directory. In my example I had it set to `std::string dir = "."`, but you can figure out the rest.