# Open the lastest downloaded file with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Below is my attempt at this problem. It's a functional script, but I have to specify the application to be used for each file type. Since this information regarding default application must be stored somewhere on Linux / Ubuntu already, how may I access them and incorporate into my script?

Also, can my script be more "elegant" in any way?

Thank you for helping a Bash script beginner! I appreciate any comment.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Open the latest file in ~/Downloads

filename=$(ls -t ~/Downloads | head -1)
filetype=$(echo -n $filename | tail -c -3)

if [ $filetype == "txt" ]; then
    leafpad ~/Downloads/$filename
elif [ $filetype == "pdf" ]; then
    evince ~/Downloads/$filename
fi
```

Comment: *"Can my script be more "elegant" in any way?"* Here's how to do it fairly robustly in a one-liner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20666511/2113226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to bash programming.  :-)

First off, I'll refer you to the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).  Great resource, lots of tips, perspectives and warnings.

One of them is the classic **[Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)** problem that your script suffers from.  The basic idea is that you don't want to trust the output of the `ls` command, because special characters like spaces and control characters may be represented in a way that doesn't allow you to *refer* to the file.

You're opening the "last" file, as determined by a sort that the `ls` command is doing.  In order to detect the most recent file *without* `ls`, we'll need some extra code.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

last=0

for filename in ~/Downloads/*; do
  when=$(stat -c '%Y' "$filename")
  if [ $when -gt $last ]; then
    last=$when
    to_open="$filename"
  fi
done

xdg-open "$to_open"
```

The idea is that we'll walk through each file in your `Downloads` directory and fine the one with the largest timestamp using the `stat` command.  Then open that file using `xdg-open`, which may already be installed on your system because it's part of a tool set that's a dependency for a number of other applications.

If you don't have xdg-open, you can probably install it from the **xdg-utils** package which using whatever package management system is around for your Linux distro.

Another possibility is `gnome-open`, which is part of the Gnome desktop (the `libgnome` package, to be precise).  YMMV.  We'd need to know more about your distro and your desktop environment to come up with better advice.

Note that if you *do* want to continue selecting your application by extension, you might want to consider using a switch instead of a series of `if`s:

```
...

case "${filename##*.}" in
  txt)
    leafpad "$filename"
    ;;
  pdf)
    xdg-open "$filename"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "ERROR: can't open '$filename'" >&2
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you! I love answers that point to relevant resources beyond the specific problem at hand.

Comment: Be a bit careful with your `~/Downloads/*` glob.  If there are no files here, then the glob will expand to the glob expression itself, which is not what you want.  To get around this, you can use the bash-specific `shopt -s nullglob` at the cost of portability.  http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html#globbing

Answer (score 2):

[How do I open a file in its default program - Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143100/how-do-i-open-a-file-in-its-default-program-linux) should help you with the first part of your question:

```
xdg-open ~/Downloads/$filename
```

As mentioned in other answers, it's best not to trust the output of `ls` in scripts, especially if you have unusual characters like newlines in your filenames.  One way to robustly get a list of filenames in a script is with the `find` command, and null-delimiting them into a pipe.

So to answer your question with a one-liner:

```
find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%C@ %p\0" | sort -zrn | { read -d '' ts file; xdg-open "$file"; }
```

Breaking it down:

- The `find` command lists files in the `~/Download` directory, but doesn't descend any deeper into subdirectories.  The filenames are printed with the given printf format, which lists a numerical timestamp, followed by a space, followed by a null delimiter.  Note the [printf format specifiers for `find`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20~/Downloads%20-maxdepth%201%20-type%20f%20-printf%20%22%25C@%20%25p%5C0%22) are different to those for regular printf
- The [`sort` command](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sort%20-zrn) numerically sorts (-n) the resulting null-delimited list (-z) by the first field (numerical timestamp).  Sort order is reversed (-r) so that the latest entry is displayed first
- The `read` command reads the timestamp and filename of the first file in the list into the `ts` and `file` variables.  `-d ''` tells `read` to use null delimiters.
- The file is opened using `xdg-open`.

Note the `read` and `xdg-open` commands are in a [curly bracket inline group](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF), so the `file` variable is in scope for both.

Answer (score 1):

[`mimeopen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/mimeopen.1p.html) might be useful?  There's an explanation of Mime types [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes).

Also - are your filetype extensions always exactly two letters, as the `tail -c -3` implies?  If they're of variable length, you may want a regular expression instead.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, `xdg-open` and `mimeopen` may be useful and more elegant; from their manpages:

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the preferred application for files of that type.
>
> [mimeopen]  tries to determine the mimetype of a file and open it with the default desktop application. If no default application is configured the user is prompted with an "open with" menu in the terminal.

For more elegance in the original script, replace
`filetype=$(echo -n $filename | tail -c -3)`
with
`filetype=${filename: -3}`
and instead of the five-lines `if`/`elif`/`fi` structure, consider using two lines as follows.

```
[ $filetype == "txt" ] && leafpad ~/Downloads/$filename
[ $filetype == "pdf" ] && evince ~/Downloads/$filename
```