# Open HTML file in the directory with C++

Tags: c++, html, linux, ubuntu

I want to open the HTML file named "myHTML.html" using C++ code in Ubuntu. The file is located in the same directory as my C++ source files.

May I know how do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Read it? Write it? Render it?

Comment: @gongzhitaao hi! I want to open it. Eg. when I run a certain method, my HTML file will be launched in mozilla or chrome. :D

Comment: Might [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143100/how-do-i-open-a-file-in-its-default-program-linux) be of some help?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you could start a process running the web browser (in the background), e.g.

```
 char cmd[256];
 char mypwd[200];
 memset (mypwd, 0, sizeof(mypwd));
 if (!getcwd(mypwd, sizeof(mypwd))) 
   { perror("getcwd"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
 snprintf (cmd, sizeof(cmd), 
           "/usr/bin/x-www-browser 'file://%s/myHTML.html' &", mypwd);
 int notok = system(cmd);
```

<sup>Of course if the current directory has a weird name (e.g. contains a quote, which is uncommon), you might end up with some [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). But it is unlikely. and you might replace `mypwd` with `"/proc/self/cwd"`</sup>

If the HTML file you want to open is builtin, e.g.`/etc/yourapp/myHTML.html` (or some other nice *fixed* file path, without naughty characters) you could just use

```
int notok = system("/usr/bin/x-www-browser /etc/yourapp/myHTML.html &");
```

or

```
int notok = system("xdg-open  /etc/yourapp/myHTML.html &");
```

or

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
   // child process
   execlp("xdg-open", "/etc/yourapp/myHTML.html", NULL);
   _exit(127);
};
```

(you may want to `waitpid` for your `pid` later)

And even better, you could make your C++ application an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) server, e.g. with [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)